# Am I invoking undefined behavior when casting back to my pointer?

Tags: c++, optimization, language-lawyer, undefined-behavior

I've been trying to figure out if this is an optimisation bug as it only seems to affect stack variables, and I wonder if there's some incorrect assumptions being made. I have this type which converts to and from a relative offset, and it has been working fine while using `reinterpret_cast`, but now I'm moving to `static_cast`, it's starting to cause issues in optimised builds. I need to get away from `reinterpret_cast` for safety certification reasons, so I don't have the option of keeping it as it is.

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Ptr
{
public:
    Ptr(const T* ptr = nullptr) : m_offset(GetOffset(ptr)) {}
    T& operator*() const noexcept { return *GetPtr(); } 
    T* get() const noexcept { return GetPtr(); }

    bool operator==(const T *ptr) const {
        // comment this back in and it stops failing
        //std::cout << "{op==" << get() << " == " << ptr << "}";
        return get() == ptr;
    }

  private:
    std::ptrdiff_t m_offset = 0;

    inline T* GetPtr() const
    {
        auto offset = m_offset;
        auto const_void_address = static_cast<const void*>(&m_offset);
        auto const_char_address = static_cast<const char*>(const_void_address);
        auto offset_address = const_cast<char*>(const_char_address);
        auto final_address  = static_cast<void*>(offset_address - offset);
        return static_cast<T*>(final_address);
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t GetOffset(const void* ptr) const
    {
        auto void_address = static_cast<const void*>(&m_offset);
        auto offset_address = static_cast<const char*>(void_address);
        auto ptr_address = static_cast<const char*>(ptr);
        return offset_address - ptr_address;
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const Ptr<int> &rp) {
    stream << rp.get();
    return stream;
}

int main() {
    int data = 123;
    Ptr<int> rp(&data);
    std::cout << "data " << data << " @ " << &data << std::endl;
    std::cout << "rp " << *rp << " get " << rp.get() << std::endl;
    std::cout << (rp == &data) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(rp.get() == &data) = " << (rp.get() == &data) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "(rp == &data) = " << (rp == &data) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

with optimisations turned on, I get output like this:

```
data 123 @ 0x7ffe79544a34
rp 123 get 0x7ffe79544a34
0
(rp.get() == &data) = 0
(rp == &data) = 0
```

Which includes some output which is clearly inconsistent with itself.

I've tested this on GCC 8,9, and 11.2.

- As soon as I drop back to `-O0`, it's fine.
- If I uncomment the `std::cout` inside the `operator==`, it's fine.
- If I go back to `reinterpret_cast` (`return reinterpret_cast<T*>(reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(&m_offset) - offset);`) it's fine.
- If I allocate data as a pointer and initialise `rp` from that, it's fine too.
- It seems to behave as I expect under clang (8 through 13 seem fine)

This feels like I am either not understanding where the UB is coming from, or there's a compiler optimisation bug here.

---

EDIT / UPDATE:

After looking at this is more detail I think the only solution is to do type punning in a semi-safe way, so I have tried this solution and it appears to work. (it appears, what I am now doing is part of C++20 and called `bit_cast`, so maybe this is valid?)

```
    inline T* GetPtr() const
    {
        auto offset = m_offset;
        intptr_t realAddress;
        auto address_of_m_offset = &m_offset;
        std::memcpy(&realAddress, &address_of_m_offset, sizeof( realAddress));
        realAddress -= m_offset;
        T *outValue;
        std::memcpy(&outValue, &realAddress, sizeof( outValue));
        return outValue;
    }

    std::ptrdiff_t GetOffset(const void* ptr) const
    {
        auto address_of_m_offset = &m_offset;
        intptr_t myAddress;
        std::memcpy(&myAddress, &address_of_m_offset, sizeof(myAddress));
        intptr_t realAddress;
        std::memcpy(&realAddress, &ptr, sizeof(realAddress));
        return static_cast<ptrdiff_t>(myAddress - realAddress);
    }
```

This no longer seems to cause a problem with GCC. I hear that std::memcpy is meant to be used for objects of same type where otherwise we would have used `reinterpret_cast`, so this makes sense to me.

Comment: Justs out of curiosity: Why store a pointer in that way? Also, just a guess, could it be that there are overflows of a signed value, which would be UB? Lastly, I'd add the "language-lawyer" tag, maybe replace the "*-cast" tags.

Comment: The easier way is to compare output from optimized and non-optimized "assemblation" :)

Comment: When the same piece of physical memory is used concurrently in different virtual address spaces, absolute pointers can't be used. That's why I need a relative pointer. This is a solution to a shared memory problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your undefined behaviour is in `GetOffset`.

This is how pointer subtraction is defined by the standard:

> When two pointer expressions `P` and `Q` are subtracted, the type of the result is an implementation-defined signed integral type; this type shall be the same type that is defined as `std::ptrdiff` in the `<cstddef>` header ([support.types.layout])
>
> - If `P` and `Q` both evaluate to null pointer values, the result is `0`.
> - Otherwise, if `P` and `Q` both point to, respectively, array elements *i* and *j* of the same array object `x`, the expression `P - Q` has the value *i - j*.
> - Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

And here, `P` (which has the address of `m_object`) and `Q` (which has the address of `data`) aren't elements of the same array, so this is undefined behaviour.

Addition and subtraction of pointers and integers is also defined in terms of array elements:

> When an expression `J` that has integral type is added to or subtracted from an expression `P` of pointer type, the result has the type of `P`.
>
> - If `P` evaluates to a null pointer value and `J` evaluates to 0, the result is a null pointer value.
> - Otherwise, if `P` points to an array element *i* of an array object `x` with *n* elements ([dcl.array]), the expression `P + J` and `J + P` (Where `J` has value *j* point to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element *i+j* of `x` if 0≤*i+j*≤*n* and the expression `P - J` points to the (possibly-hypothetical) array element *i-j* of `x` if 0≤*i-j*≤n.
> - Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

The pointer subtraction happens at `offset_address - offset`, where `P` is the address of `m_offset` and `offset` is probably some positive number. `m_offset` is the first element of the array, so *i-j* < 0

So, the compiler can see that `GetPtr` returns a pointer relative to the `m_offset` (in the `char[sizeof(Ptr<int>)]` array that aliases the object), so it cannot equal the address of `data` (without UB), and thus an optimizer can replace `(rp.get() == &data)` with `false`.

When you use `ptrdiff_t`, no such restriction on addition or subtraction exists. And though the standard doesn't guarantee that `reinterpret_cast<char*>(reinterpret_cast<intptr_t>(char_pointer) + n) == char_pointer + n` (pointers mapping linearly as you would expect) this is what happens when compiling with gcc on common architectures.

Comment: Interesting theory, but when I put back the `reinterpret_cast` into the GetOffset, the behaviour does not change. I added `return reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(&m_offset) - reinterpret_cast<std::ptrdiff_t>(ptr);` and it's still presenting the same problem. The problem seems to reside in GetPtr somehow. - as you say, it's the fact they aren't from the same array, right?

Comment: Are we in "C++ does not have a defined behaviour solution for this problem" without `reinterpret_cast` terrain here?

Comment: @RichardFabian Yes even after you change `GetOffset` to use reinterpret_cast, then the expression `offset_address - offset` would be UB. If you want to use addition and subtraction, you have to `reinterpret_cast` to avoid undefined behaviour (and instead have implementation defined behaviour).